# Python how to count group size if there is remainder

Tags: python

"If the division does not go evenly, there may be fewer students in one group, but all others must have the desired number."

```
x = float(input("How many students"))
y = float(input("What is the group size?"))

division = (x / y)
remainder = (x % y)


print(f"Group size: ")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `y` is group size, no?

Comment: y is group size

Comment: "What is your question?"

How to count group size

Comment: Let's say x = 13 and y = 4. What's your expected output?

Comment: sounds like you want to round the result of the division up to the nearest whole number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do it like this:-**

```
import math 
x = float(input("How many students"))
y = float(input("What is the group size?"))

division = (x / y)
remainder = (x % y)
if remainder == 0:
    print(f" No of Groups: {division}")
else:
    print("No of Groups:", math.ceil(division))
```

Comment: The test is useless, you can do directly: `print(f" No of Groups: {math.ceil(x/y)}")`, if y is a divider of x, then `math.ceil(x/y) == x/y`